# How To create debug apk file in react native

Tags: react-native

I have a react native project. it works fine on android. but can not create debug apk file of this project.

Comment: When you run `react-native run-android` gradle creates a debug apk of the project. you can find this apk in `project root/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug` folder

Answer (score 0):

first run this command in your terminal

```
npm run react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

after this go inside your android folder by running this command

```
cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

then you can get your apk from this location
`app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk`